# { } assign operator inside a constructor implementation => errors

Tags: c++, constructor, operators, assign

Isn't the {} operator an assign operator? Plus, why does `int val{10};` works inside main, but the assignment bellow in the constructor is illegal?

**Check the examples**

*This code works:*

```
class Time{
    int _H, _M, _S;
public:
    Time(int h = 0, int m = 0, int s = 0){_H={h};
                                          _M={m}; 
                                          _S={s};};
    ~Time(){}

};
```

*This does not:*

```
class Time{
    int _H, _M, _S;
public:
    Time(int h = 0, int m = 0, int s = 0){_H{h};  //here is the difference
                                          _M{m}; 
                                          _S{s};};
    ~Time(){}

};
```

*The message I received from GCC was this one*

```
classes.cpp: In constructor ‘Time::Time(int, int, int)’:
classes.cpp:48:44: error: expression cannot be used as a function
  Time(int h = 0, int m = 0, int s = 0){_H{h};
                                            ^
classes.cpp:49:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
              _M{m}; 
                ^
classes.cpp:50:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
              _S{s};};
                ^
```

Comment: Do not use identifiers which start with an underscore and then a capital letter! These are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is not an assignment operator. It is uniform initialization. Here is the correct way,

```
class Time{
    int _H, _M, _S;
public:
    Time(int h = 0, int m = 0, int s = 0):_H{h},
                                         _M{m}, 
                                         _S{s}{}
    ~Time(){}
};
```

The reason it is better because in C++, not like C# or Java, the initialization of the class members happens before the execution of statements inside the constructor.

The reason it works in your first example is because `=` is an assignment. `_H={h};` will call the assignment operator. But `_H{h};` is not valid C++ syntax. And `_H(h);` which I believe is what you have based on the error message will try to call a function `_H`.

Comment: @Sir, although the `{}` is an uniform initialization operator, do you know why the use of it inside the main does close to same to `=` but, in my example it does not? [thank for you answer]